# Ensure that quorem is returning a polynomial OR extract part with negative powers from Laurent-polynomial

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, polynomials

I am using quorem to do multivariate polynomial division. Unfortunately matlab is not returning polynomials in some cases. Is there some options for quorem that I always get a polynomial. A short example where this occurs is:

```
    syms x y;
    p=x + y + (x*y + 1)*(- y^2 + x + 1);
    [q,r]=quorem(pp,1+x*y,x); expand(q),expand(r)
    [q,r]=quorem(pp,1+x*y,y); expand(q),expand(r)
```

What I want is some function QUOREM such that

```
    [qq,rr]=QUOREM(pp,1+x*y)
    qq=(x*y + 1)*(- y^2 + x + 1)
    rr=x+y
```

A workaround would be to extract the part with negative powers from the quotient and recompute quotient and remainder. But for that approach I could not find any function which extracts the negative part from a Laurent polynomial.

EDIT: Typo corrected.